# How to add quasar colors to my nuxt3 unocss project?

Tags: nuxt.js, quasar-framework, nuxt3, unocss

I wanted to know if there is any way to add quasar colors file to my nuxt 3 project Im using naiveUI and unoCss and I need those colors with those specifications like : red-5 , red-9 etc..
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Create a **css file** in your project.

**2.** Add the codes found in this github gist link to your css file:
[css codes gist](https://gist.github.com/coderdal/323fba78bb56f2b41dfc710e74cf9eac)

Include the css file in your pages and you're ready to go!

**Note:** if you want to use these rules in your whole application, don't forget to include this css file in your project globally (global css).